# How to insert value to a variable from HNA Prcedure

Tags: hana

I want to insert a value into a local hana variable from a procedure. Please suggest a solution for me.

This is my code:

```
Create Procedure "Test1"(IN DocEntry Int)
    language SQLSCRIPT

    AS
    Begin
    Declare VehID Nvarchar(3);
    Declare Oddo Numeric;
    Declare PreDate Date;
    Declare CurDate Date;
    Declare Log_KM Numeric;

            Select"U_AdDate", "U_ItemCode"  INTO CurDate, VehID from "@DCC_WORDR" Where  "DocEntry" = :DocEntry ;

            Select Top 1 "U_AdDate", "U_Log_KM" INTO PreDate, Oddo  from "@DCC_WORDR" Where "U_ItemCode" = '358' and "DocEntry" <> :DocEntry Order By "U_AdDate" DESC;

            --Select :CurDate, :VehID, :Predate, :Oddo from Dummy;

            LogKM := (CALL "TRANSCARGOLTDLIVE"."DCC_Get_KM" (:VehID, :PreDate, :CurDate));

    End;
```

Answer (score 0):

To have variable values assigned by a procedure, you have to use the procedure OUT or IN/OUT parameters.

So, your code could look like this:

```
Create Procedure "Test1"(IN DocEntry Int)
language SQLSCRIPT

AS
Begin
Declare VehID Nvarchar(3);
Declare Oddo Numeric;
Declare PreDate Date;
Declare CurDate Date;
Declare Log_KM Numeric;

        Select "U_AdDate", "U_ItemCode"  INTO CurDate, VehID 
        from "@DCC_WORDR" 
        Where  "DocEntry" = :DocEntry ;

        Select Top 1 "U_AdDate", "U_Log_KM" INTO PreDate, Oddo  
        from "@DCC_WORDR" 
        Where "U_ItemCode" = '358' 
        and "DocEntry" <> :DocEntry 
        Order By "U_AdDate" DESC;


        CALL "TRANSCARGOLTDLIVE"."DCC_Get_KM" 
                 (:VehID, :PreDate, :CurDate, :LogKM);

End;
```

For that to work, the DCC_GET_KM procedure has to have the LogKM parameter as an OUT parameter.

Other than that, please do yourself a huge favor and format your SQL statements properly. Also, as you assign PreDate and CurDate via queries, make sure to initialize those variables with reasonable values, in case the queries return empty result sets.

- Lars